# WPF Collage ListView Possible Isn't?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The video via the YouTube Data API v3 from the search page, i'm taking names and pictures and listing it in listview. Then came a list of collage in my mind.

Is it possible to do something like the following example?

[image]

at the same time, i want to automatically resize according to the screen. Like side by side with this method.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Liste" Margin="0,106,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}">
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel 
                Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth),
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                IsItemsHost="True"
                />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

I'm waiting for your ideas and suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use a [Relative Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel.aspx) instead of a ListBox

Comment: Relative panel is for UWP apps, not for WPF apps.
I'm afraid building a collage panel is not easy for WPF beginner. You'll need to create a custom panel.